# How to allocate an unknown number of variables corresponding to input arguments

Tags: python, matrix, command-line-arguments, allocation

I have n files .txt, where each file contains a matrix. I want to allocate a variable for each matrix, reading the corresponding file.

I do not know a priori the number of files specified by the command line arguments.

Therefore, I need a sort of "for loop" which reads a file at a time, and allocates the corresponding matrix to a variable.

For example:

```
python allocate_matrices.py file1 file2 file3
```

where:
file1 is:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

file2 is:

```
0 1
3 4
6 7
```

and file3 is:

```
0 1 2 5
3 4 5 6
6 7 8 7
```

My idea is to use a sort of loop:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(len(sys.argv)-1):
    file[i] = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[i+1])
```

but I do not know what kind of structure I should use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not know a priori the number of files specified by the command line arguments.

Sure you do:  `len(sys.argv) - 1`.

Even if you didn't, lists in Python are not fixed size. So why not do this:

```
matrices = []                       # Allocate an empty list
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:       # Skip argv[0], name of script
    mat = np.loadtxt(filename)      # Read a matrix
    matrices.append(mat)            # Append it to the list
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I can call the first matrix by matrices[0], the first row of the first matrix by matrices[0][0], and the element (i,j) by matrices[0][i][j], right?